# Observe the ping of socketio client at server side

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I know that the socketio client sends a ping at every 25 secs (heartbeat interval) and gets a response back from the server. I want to print this ping from client on the server side and also if possible capture the ping response sent back by the node server.

I tried using

```
socket.on("ping", function(data) {
    console.log("received ping");
});
socket.on("pong", function(data) {
    console.log("received pong");
});
```

both on client and the server side but i am not able to capture them

Comment: These are meant as internal messages, not for public consumption.  What are you really trying to do?  You can see the individual messages in the Chrome debugger/network tab if you just want to see that they exist.

Comment: I am trying to understand the ping behavior, like you said I can see it in Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This snippet can run on the server. The documentation for the underlying [engine.io server socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/engine.io#socket) specifies the parameters for the event listeners `packet` and `packetCreate`, and that object is located on [`socket.conn`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-conn):

```
socket.conn.on('packet', function (packet) {
  if (packet.type === 'ping') console.log('received ping');
});

socket.conn.on('packetCreate', function (packet) {
  if (packet.type === 'pong') console.log('sending pong');
});
```

Turns out the engine.io documentation for these events are wrong. The arguments are not `type` and `data`, it is a single argument `packet` that contains the properties `type` and `data`, according to the source for [the `packet` event](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L91) and [the `packetCreate` event](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L399).

Comment: Is there any code needed for the client in order to make this to work? Placing that code on the server simple doesn't work (there's no message in console log)

Comment: thank you, do you know any solution for the first part of this question, I'm also trying to print the ping from client on the server console log.

Comment: Is that what I thought too, but it's actually not working, it won't throw any errors neither. My code looks like `const socketio = require('socket.io'); const io = socketio(server, { pingInterval: 5000, pingTimeout: 60000, });` I'm using exactly the snipet on your answer. I tryied also to place it under `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){...});` just like for `socket.on('disconnect', reason => {...});` event, but none of those tests produce any results. My socket.io version is 2.0.4

Comment: @Adry sorry for the confusion, thank you for pointing out that this answer was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work, we just need to reverse it, i.e.

```
socket.conn.on('packet', (packet) => {
  if (packet.type === 'pong') console.log('sending pong');
});
socket.conn.on('packetCreate', (packet) => {
  if (packet.type === 'ping') console.log('received ping')
});
```

on 'packet' event we get the packet type as pong and on event `packetCreate` we get the `packet.type` as ping.